# Bug in Hive query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, syntax, hive

What is wrong with syntax of this query -

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE access_performance_partition
SELECT request
    ,exec_time
    ,rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY request ORDER BY cast(exec_time AS BIGINT) DESC
        ) AS AddedRank
    ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY request) AS RequestCount
FROM access_performance;
```

It is showing

```
-FAILED: Parse Error: line 4:39 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM near 'over' in from clause
```

Answer (score 0):

Which hive version do you have?
Looks like it supported starting from 0.11, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4048